# How can I create Breeze Metadata from Sequelize DataTypes using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, breeze

I am using `sequelize-auto` to generate data types from my database and it works great. The result is something like this:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
return sequelize.define('ReportTasks', {
    ReportTaskID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    BatchID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        references: {
            model: 'ReportBatches',
            key: 'BatchID'
        }
    },
    Name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    Year: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
    },
    Month: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
    },
    CompanyKey: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
    },
    CompanyName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    StartDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true
    },
    EndDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true
    },
    Status: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'ReportTasks'
});
```

};

Now I am trying to setup Breeze server and it needs metadata. The examples pull the metadata from a `json` file, but I want to build the metadata from my models. How can I achieve this?

This is the code from the example (http://breeze.github.io/doc-node-sequelize/introduction.html):

```
function createSequelizeManager() {
    var metadata = readMetadata();
    var sm = new SequelizeManager(dbConfig, sequelizeOptions);
    sm.importMetadata(metadata);
    return sm;
}

function readMetadata() {
    var filename = "TodoMetadata.json";
    if (!fs.existsSync(filename)) {
        throw new Error("Unable to locate file: " + filename);
    }
    var metadata = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
    return JSON.parse(metadata);
}
```

Comment: Currently the [MetadataMapper](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.node/blob/master/breeze-sequelize/src/MetadataMapper.js) only goes the other direction, from [Breeze metadata](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/metadata-schema.html#metadata-example) to Sequelize.  It would be great to have a tool to go the other way, particularly when using `sequelize-auto`.

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks for the comment... I actually hacked out a tool to go the other way and got it working... very ugly and doesn't support most data types but works for me for now

Answer (score 1):

This now appears to be handled here:  [Breeze-Sequelize](http://breeze.github.io/doc-node-sequelize/introduction.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I don't see where/how to use this to generate the metadata information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So... I hacked out a super basic beginnings of a tool to do this reverse mapping. It doesn't support any datatypes except int, string, bool, date, but that's all I need for now.

It does the job of taking models generated by `sequelize-auto` and creating a semi-usable metadata spec for breeze.

Here is the general idea (don't judge me i know its bad):

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var SequelizeAuto = require('sequelize-auto')
var fs = require('fs');
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

var config = require('./config');

var auto = new SequelizeAuto(config.database.name, config.database.username, config.database.password, {
    dialect: config.database.dialect,
    dialectModulePath: config.database.dialectModulePath,
    dialectOptions: {
        driver: config.database.driver,
        instanceName: config.database.instanceName
    },
    directory: './models',
    host: config.database.host,
    username: config.database.username,
    password: config.database.password,
    database: config.database.name,
    tables: config.database.tables,
    define: {
        timestamps: false
    }
});

var tables;
var foreignKeys;

var metadata = {
    "metadataVersion": "1.0.5",
    "namingConvention": "noChange",
    "localQueryComparisonOptions": "caseInsensitiveSQL",
    "dataServices": [
      {
          "serviceName": "breeze/",
          "hasServerMetadata": true,
          "jsonResultsAdapter": "webApi_default",
          "useJsonp": false
      }
    ],
    "structuralTypes": [],
};

auto.run(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    createMetadata(auto.tables);

});

function createMetadata(tables) {

    // now create metadata
    Object.keys(auto.tables).forEach(function (tableName) {

        var table = auto.tables[tableName];
        var structuralType = transformTable(tableName);

        var fieldIndex = 0;
        Object.keys(table).forEach(function (field) {
            var val = table[field];
            var dataProperty = transformField(fieldIndex, field, val);
            structuralType.dataProperties.push(dataProperty);
            fieldIndex++;
        });

        // add to metadata
        metadata.structuralTypes.push(structuralType);
    });

    console.log('metadata', metadata);

    // write to file
    jsonfile.writeFile('./metadata/metadata.json', metadata, { spaces: 2 }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

function transformTable(tableName) {
    return {
        "shortName": tableName,
        "namespace": "Models",
        "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity",
        "defaultResourceName": tableName,
        "dataProperties": []
    };
}

function transformField(fieldIndex, field, val) {
    var result = {
        "name": field,
        "dataType": _dataTypeMap[val.type] || 'String',
        "isPartOfKey": fieldIndex == 0 ? true : false,
        "isNullable": !!val.allowNull,
        "defaultValue": val.defaultValue,
        "validators": [],
    };

    if (!val.allowNull) {
        result.validators.push({ "name": "required" });
    }

    return result;
}

// todo - add support for all types
var _dataTypeMap = {
    NVARCHAR: 'String',
    BIT: 'Boolean',
    DATETIME: 'DateTime',
    INT: 'Int32'
};
```